# Getting output in PLSQL procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Normally, in SQL Developer, if one does, let's say, `INSERT` statement, then there is an output in `Script output`:

```
insert into a (a) values (1);

1 rows inserted.
```

If, then, we compile it into procedure:

```
create or replace procedure testp as
begin
  insert into a (a) values (1);
end;

PROCEDURE TESTP compiled
```

and make call to it:

```
execute testp

anonymous block completed
```

There is no output about how many rows were inserted. How then, can we turn on detailed output in procedure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want "detailed output" that will be printed out for users running a procedure interactively in an IDE with appropriate settings enabled, you could

```
create or replace procedure testp as
begin
  insert into a (a) values (1);
  dbms_output.put_line( sql%rowcount || ' row inserted. ' );
end;
```

Assuming that the caller is using an application that knows how to display what is written to `dbms_output` (i.e. an IDE), that they've enabled `dbms_output` (using the `dbms_output` window in SQL Developer), that they've allocated a sufficient buffer, etc., the caller will see "1 row inserted" (you could add more code if you want to handle the grammar of singular/ plural programmatically).

Why do you want to have that sort of output though?  That usually implies that you should be doing some real logging to a log table of some sort rather than hoping that an interactive user is running your code and seeing the output.

Comment: +1 on implementing REAL logging. Sticking dbms_outputs in code for debugging purposes that will ever hit production risks having sessions blow up on exceeding the dbms_output buffer once it gets out in the real world.

Comment: So true dbms_output in prod env can create a total mess.

Comment: Agreed dbms_output is for basic debugging in dev/test environments, and its output is not displayed by default in most applications as it takes additional code to retrieve it. However I have seen it used well in production batches. The Perl code called from the job scheduler automatically called dbms_output.get_lines and printed the output so that it was included in the logfile. Not as good as a log table perhaps (and still risks PGA problems with excessive buffer size) but it did the job.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no output about how many rows were inserted. How then, can we turn on detailed output in procedure?

SQL and PL/SQL are not same. In PL/SQL, you could use **SQL%ROWCOUNT** to get the total number of rows affected by the **DML**.

To get this in the output buffer, use **DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE**.

For example,

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(SQL%ROWCOUNT || ' rows were inserted' );
```

Make sure you enable DBMS_OUTPUT in your client.

In **SQL*Plus**, do:

```
set serveroutput on
```

Other GUI based client tools have an option to enable it.

I wouldn't suggest DBMS_OUTPUT in production though. You could use it for logging purpose. Like you want to log the number of rows affected by a program on daily basis.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that instead of going for dbms_output try to incorporate the OUT parameter and assign SQL%ROWCOUNT to this variable. Keeping dbms_output in prod env is a really bad idea.

```
create or replace procedure testp
(p_row_cnt_out OUT PLS_INTEGER)
 as
begin
  insert into a (a) values (1);
  p_row_cnt_out:= SQL%ROWCOUNT;
  --dbms_output.put_line( sql%rowcount || ' row inserted. ' );
end;
```